# Regex expression in C++ and double backslash

Tags: c++, regex, qt-creator, backslash

I'm reading a text file in the form of

```
People list
[Jane]
Female
31
...
```

and for each line I want to loop through and find the line that contains "[...]"
For example, [Jane]

I came up with the regex expression

> "(^[\w+]$)"

which I tested that it works using regex101.com.
However, when I try to use that in my code, it fails to match with anything.
Here's my code:

```
void Jane::JaneProfile() {
    // read each line, for each [title], add the next lines into its array
    std::smatch matches;
    for(int i = 0; i < m_numberOfLines; i++) { // #lines in text file
        std::regex pat ("(^\[\w+\]$)");
        if(regex_search(m_lines.at(i), matches, pat)) {
            std::cout << "smatch " << matches.str(0) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "smatch.size() = " << matches.size() << std::endl;

        } else
            std::cout << "wth" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, all the lines go to the else loop and nothing matches...

I searched up for answers, but I got confused when I saw that for C++ you have to use double backslashes instead one backslash to escape... But it didn't work for my code even when I used double backslashes...
Where did I go wrong?

By the way, I'm using Qt Creator 3.6.0 Based on (Desktop) Qt 5.5.1 (Clang 6.1 (Apple), 64 bit)

---Edit----

I tried doing:

```
std::regex pat (R"(^\[\\w+\]$)");
```

But I get an error saying

> Use of undeclared identifier 'R'

I already have `#include <regex>` but do I need to include something else?

Comment: Maybe you need to use C++11 raw literal strings so you don't need to escape anything. `std::string str=R"(...)";` so it would be something like `td::regex pat (R"((^\[\w+\]$))");`

Comment: Ah, I tried that but I get an error 'use of undeclared identifier 'R'' - do you perhaps know why?

Comment: What version of compiler is it?

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator 3.6.0 Based on (Desktop) Qt 5.5.1 (Clang 6.1 (Apple), 64 bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either escape the backslashes or use the raw character version with a prefix that won't appear in the regex:

escaped:

```
std::regex pat("^\\[\\w+\\]$");
```

raw character string:

```
std::regex pat(R"regex(^\[\w+\]$)regex");
```

working demo (adapted from OPs posted code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto test_data =
    "People list\n"
    "[Jane]\n"
    "Female\n"
    "31";

    // initialise test data
    std::istringstream source(test_data);
    std::string buffer;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    while (std::getline(source, buffer)) {
        lines.push_back(std::move(buffer));
    }

    // test the regex

    // read each line, for each [title], add the next lines into its array
    std::smatch matches;
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) { // #lines in text file
        static const std::regex pat ("(^\\[\\w+\\]$)");
        if(regex_search(lines.at(i), matches, pat)) {
            std::cout << "smatch " << matches.str() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "smatch.size() = " << matches.size() << std::endl;
        } else
            std::cout << "wth" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
wth
smatch [Jane]
smatch.size() = 2
wth
wth
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use the first expression, I don't seem to get a match from the text file; and when I use the second expression I still get the error "use of undeclared identifier 'R'" :(

Comment: @Ceria tested on my mac with apple clang.

Comment: @Ceria just a thought - are you on a windows machine? If so, it's likely that your text file terminates lines with CR/LF rather than LF as on unix. If so, you'll need to strip the CR from each string as you read it in... or get a proper operating system :)

Comment: @RichardHodges: From the question: _"Clang 6.1 (Apple)"_ Besides, [I don't think the anti-Windows personal-OS-preference pontificating is necessary here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318809/560648).

Comment: @RichardHodges Thank you! I copied the regex part directly and it worked! I seem to have wrote something weird. :)

Comment: @RichardHodges  What? The C and C++ I/O libraries perform line ending conversion for text streams. If you're running on Windows, and open a Windows text file as a text stream, your code does not see carriage returns. (You will see them on a Unix box when opening a file that came from Windows and wasn't converted to the local format.)

Comment: @Kaz even for getline? I must admit it's been a while since I wrote anything on windows but I have memories of having to always strip off those damn CRs.

Comment: @RichardHodges Another question but, does smatch.size() supposed to return 2? There was only one [Jane] in the file so I thought it will return 1...

Comment: @Ceria size() is 1 (for the complete match) plus one for each submatch (which I thought only occurred when you use subexpressions in the regex). In this case, str(1) is the same as str(0), so I guess if there are no subexpressions, the entire regex is treated as one big subexpression. I have no idea why. Each line is matched separately in this example, the 2 does not mean 2 matches, it means that the one match for this line has 2 items in the smatch structure. suggest you play around with the example to learn more, plus read here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search